# Function within a function involving each column of a DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

As the question states, I'm trying to learn how to run a function on each element belonging to a column within a DataFrame without having to define that column directly. The point is that I would like to be able to enter any given set of `DataFrame` and find each element within each column that fulfills a particular condition.

The sample that I've included illustrates what I'm trying to do. I know the below doesn't work and I thought that writing `def fun(dataframe[column])` would do the trick but the syntax is incorrect, unfortunately.

Basically, the reason for this is that I have multiple sets of data where I'd like to locate each element that is above a set threshold.

Thanks a lot in advance!

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(3, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))
def fun(dataframe):
  for column in dataframe:  
     def fun(column):  
        mean= sum(column)/len(column)
        print (mean)
        for element in column:
            if element < mean*1.1:
                element = 0
            print (element)
fun(df)
```

Comment: Why is there any need for the inner function (also, it has the same name as the outer function)? Also, you should be able to do all of this without a `for` loop if I understand correctly. If your current approach doesn't work, it might be better to include a small example of an input and output DF.

Comment: The whole point of pandas is to eliminate the need to do these operations manually... Take a look at the mean function and conditional assignment.

Comment: Because I've got multiple csv files and each file has at most 100 columns. It feels like it would simplify a lot if I wouldn't have to keep writing the column name to run the function.

Answer (score 1):

As @MadPhysicist mentioned in a comment, pandas was created to reduce the need for explicit for-looping.

If I understand your specific case correctly, you intend to replace with zero any element that is less than 1.1 times the mean value of its column. Here's one way to do that in idiomatic pandas:

```
# Set a random seed for repeatability
np.random.seed(314159)

# Create example data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(3, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))
df
    A   B   C
0  11  34  93
1  79   0  81
2  66  43  71

# By default, df.mean() computes the mean of each numeric column (not row)
df.mean()
A    52.000000
B    25.666667
C    81.666667
dtype: float64

# We can use boolean indexing to replace values less than
# 1.1 * column mean with zero
# docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing
df[df < 1.1 * df.mean()] = 0

df
    A   B   C
0   0  34  93
1  79   0   0
2  66  43   0
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at boolean indexing. Is it not recommended to use functions for this task? Two additional reasons that I thought it would be beneficial is because I'd also like to:


1) Divide any non-zero element with the mean to get a more simple scale (I'm currently working with 10^4, which doesn't look too good, is arbitrary and inconvenient)


2) Be able to quickly apply the code to a new DataFrame. This is because I still have to carry out the same experimental measurements under different conditions which means I will, in the end, have around 18 different csv-files.

Comment: Just to clarify further, I've managed to accomplish the task using `df.apply(fun_column, axis=0)` to apply the function on each column. However, I'm still interested in alternative methods as I'm having troubles with "overwriting" the old dataframe with the modified values, like you just did. After I execute my code, each new element is printed correctly (I added a print function temporarily just to see if the execution is correct), but the dataframe remains the same. I might be making a mistake with how I'm returning the value.

Comment: @Raydoc, I wouldn't use nested functions for this task because pandas accomplishes it in a faster (if you're using IPython/Jupyter, compare speeds with `%timeit df[df < 1.1 * df.mean()] = 0` versus `%timeit fun(df)`) and in a more readable way. Sometimes you'll need custom functions to `apply` to a DF's columns, but that's overkill in this case. To divide elements by column mean, simply run `df/df.mean()`. Zero elements will be unaffected.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that when I woke up this morning. Must've been really sleepy (it was around 4 am). In terms of speed, would you recommend that I avoid adding even one function? With this, I've solved the issue for one DataFrame but it would obviously be tedious to copy-paste the code multiple times to apply it to a different DataFrame. Would you do it in another way? I've only been working with Python for around a day, without prior programming experience so there is obviously still a lot I need to learn. I really appreciate the feedback!

Comment: If I understand your needs, I'd say it is a bit "wordy" to apply a helper function, since there is a fast and readable (once you get used to it!) pandas solution. But if your code works now, and is fast enough for your needs, then there is little need to modify it; programmer time is valuable :) You would ideally make your code general enough to work on multiple DFs without the need for copy-pasting.